# How to show loader during multiple api calls in a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have two API's

First API returns list of items which I am iterating to get each item's detailed data.

Here's the code

```
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async() => {
      setLoader(true);
      const users = await getUsers();
      const promises = users.map(async (user) => {
          let userData = await getUsersDetailedData(user.userId);
          return userData
      });
      let finalUsers = await Promise.all(promises);
      setLoader(false);
    }
    fetchUsers();
  }, [])
```

I am updating loader state before the api call and after call but it is not working.

Loader state is updating these many times and loader is not displaying
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eohil.png)

Comment: What is not working specifically? Is the loader not displaying or something else? Have you checked to see if the `loader` state is changing how you expect it to be?

Comment: The code seems right, if you do not add more info or more code, it will be hard to help, here you can see a working example of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e3mnqk

Comment: @NickParsons loader state is updating, but it is updating 6-7 times and loader is not displaying. I have  added an image with the question.

Comment: @aanc.d Where are you doing that `console.log()`. It would help if you can create an example of this issue using a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/5648954) or something like stackblitz/codesandbox. You don't need to share your entire project, just a small example to reproduce the issue you're having (see: [mre])

Comment: Code is perfectly fine, loader was hidden under some div. Sorry, it was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way,

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUsers = async() => {
    const users = await getUsers();
    const promises = users.map(async (user) => {
        let userData = await getUsersDetailedData(user.userId);
        return userData
    });
    let finalUsers = Promise.all(promises);
    return finalUsers;
  }
  setLoader(true);
  fetchUsers().then(res=>{
    setLoader(false);
  });
}, [])
```